# Obj-C using @selector on a static method from a static method in the same class?

Tags: objective-c, static, callback, selector, static-methods

I have two static methods/selectors in the same class, one passes the other as a callback to an external method. However, how I have it coded I get an error. This worked when both the methods were instance methods, and I've read it can work when the first method is an instance method using [self class]. However, I haven't found information when both are static, and I haven't got it to work.

```
+(void)Validate {
    Callback *managerCallback = [[[Callback alloc] initWithTarget:self Action:@selector(Parse:)] autorelease];
    ...
}

+(void)Parse:(Callback *)managerCallback {
    ...
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just some style tips: both `Validate` and `Parse should begin with a lowercase letter, and the init method should be `initWithTarget:action:` (each part of the selector begins with a lowercase).

Comment: Objective-C does not have static methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Callback *managerCallback = [[[Callback alloc] initWithTarget:self Action:@selector(Parse:)] autorelease];</strike>

That line of code is setup to call the instance method `Parse:`, not a class method as you have it defined.

Objective-C does not have static methods.  It has class methods and instance methods.

As well, your methods should start with lowercase letters.

Herp-da-derp.   Dave is right.

Given this:

```
+(void)Validate {
    Callback *managerCallback = [[[Callback alloc] initWithTarget:self Action:@selector(Parse:)] autorelease];
    ...
}

+(void)Parse:(Callback *)managerCallback {
    ...
}
```

Some comments:

- methods should start with lowercase letters
- it is exceedingly odd to use a class in such a role;  even if you really only ever need one of 'em, use an instance.   At the least, the instance is a convenient bucket to toss state in and it'll make refactoring in the future much easier if you ever need two.
- The above pattern makes the assumption (and I ASSumed) that the instance of `Callback` is retained.   For callbacks, timers, and some other patterns, this is typical; retain the target until the target is called for the last time.  Then release (or autorelease).   However, notification centers do not do this.  Nor are delegates retained, typically.

Comment: Yes, thank you, but how do I set it up to call a class method?

Comment: It is?  `self` in a Class method is the `Class`, so if the target is a `Class` and the selector is `Parse:`, then (presumably) the `Callback` will be doing `[target performSelector:action withObject:foo]`, which should invoke `+[MyClass Parse:]`...  Have I missed something?

Comment: How I have it written now it throws a exc_bad_access exception when it attempts to call it back.

Comment: Correction, the problem I was having was the callback object was autoreleasing before it was calling the method. Taking off autorelease fixed it.

Comment: -methods should start with lowercase letters: Thanks, it's a habit I have from C#/.Net.

Comment: -it is exceedingly odd to use a class in such a role: I am used to using static methods in C#/.Net to validate user credentials against the database and it's a practice I see used often. However although it works perfectly fine and I don't see a problem with it, if that's not appropriate here I can change how I'm using it so it's in line with Obj-C coding standards.

Comment: -The above pattern makes the assumption (and I ASSumed) that the instance of Callback is retained: I release it after I call the callback's method in whatever class/method it's called in. Autorelease was releasing it before then (presumably when the method it was created in ended.)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the code is written correctly to do what I wanted to, but because callback was set to autorelease, the object was getting released before the callback was being processed.